# Break Loop in python without pressing Ctr-C, "agnostic" to OS

Tags: python

An easy way to end an infinite for loop in python is by using Ctrl-C, e.g.:

```
try:
    while True:
       print '-',
except  KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'done'
```

However, I want to use some other than Ctrl-C key because on other colleagues machines that might be interpreted by their gui environment (e.g. pycharm) as copy. Is there a way to do this? I need a solution that works both in windows and linux...

Comment: CTRL+C is only copy if you have selected text, otherwise it works as intended.

Comment: well, not in PyCharm in the above example... In my tests (win7, python2, PyCharm 2017.1 community edition), when I press ctrl-c on the debug console while there is output, it selects what is currently printing then copies it... Not sure if its a bug or a feature, in some other occasion, i might have found this a good thing....

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> on Linux sends a kill signal to the Python process.  I don't think the Python script will be able to override the default behavior of the operating system.

Comment: Ok, we go away from python here. But I think Ctrl+C sends SIGINT, which is behaving in most cases like SIGKILL (you can send SIGKILL using kill -9 ( 9 because SIGKILL==9 in the OS code). The difference between the two is that SIGINT is maskable, while SIGKILL is as you mention not.

Comment: Here are the details, check the paragraph for SIGKILL and SIGIN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC) Basically Ctr-C can be masked (meaning to override the default OS behavior)